# variables within a new command

Tags: macros

The integers modulo n, given by

```
\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}
```

is cumbersome to write. Accordingly, I would like to set up a new command that allows me to specify an input 'n'. Something like

```
\newcommand{\Z[character]}{\mathbb{Z}/[character]\mathbb{Z}}
```

But the above code is not right. Does anyone have any idea how this might be done?

Comment: This might be a little grumpy of me, but if you google "latex newcommand" you get all manner of links describing how it works, including this feature.  The LaTeX wikibook (the first result) is a good source, by the way.

Answer (score 10):

```
\newcommand\Z[1]{\mathbb{Z}/#1\mathbb{Z}}
```

Comment: And use it as `$\Z{n}$`.

Answer (score 10):

If you want it to work in normal text mode too, i.e. without dollar signs:

```
\newcommand{\Z}[1]{\ensuremath{\mathbb{Z}/#1\mathbb{Z}}}
```

Comment: Eek, sorry. This is nearly a duplicate of Leo's. That'll learn me to refresh...

Comment: It's fine. This question is trivial for all experienced LaTeX users, but fewer ones know `\ensuremath`.